# Is it possible to beat The Ensign without accepting the food at the beginning?

Tags: a-dark-room

I've gotten to "the end?" once so far. I upgraded the ship to 10/10, got pretty far, but eventually crashed. The stats screen showed

```
food refused: no
accomplished the impossible: no
```

Since I don't know what achieving the impossible is (I'm guessing surviving the asteroids), I'm trying to beat the game without accepting the food/supplies at the beginning, but I keep starving or running out of water really early on. I have no compass anymore, and the game is taunting me, encouraging me to give up. I've died early the last several times and nothing seems to be changing. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I just found out what "the impossible" is: you have to kill the defector (199 HP) that the developer (the guy you meet in the very NW corner) sends after you. I still haven't beat it without taking the food :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I refused the food and upgraded my stats with leather gear until I defeated the first defector after getting iron gear. Then it kept sending me new defectors until I died (I killed 3 or 4) and it said I had done the impossible after each kill.

This is challenging and takes real planning and some luck to pull off - the occultist needs to be close enough to home base to carry enough food and teeth/flesh/eyes.

Wewt.

Answer (score 1):

Refusing the food means no compass.  It's entirely possible to do fine without this, but you'll need to remember that food lasts 3 steps and water is one per step.  Once you find the T, C, I and A, you'll be in super solid shape.

You'll die.  A lot.  You're supposed to.

The impossible is REALLY hard.  If you've got hugs weapons and bolas, maybe.  I managed it once thus far.  Yikes.

Once you figure out how to increase your vision range, you'll be able to find things and navigating the map becomes much easier.

I've yet to get past the final flight...not sure you can (flown with 30 hp and still got swatted down), but maybe the recent secrets upgrade will answer that one.

Happy exploring...and visit all the houses you can:  some have some rather fun moments!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've played without refusing food a good 20+ times and I'm finally almost done with it. I've defeated the hard defector each time I've faced him (he's cake work with 2 bolas and full range of weps, plus I had +3 melee and +3 health at the time). It isn't indeed possible to beat just gotta watch your water and food early on. Look for the tannery immediately after clearing both houses by the swamp, it's always close to the middle. I have 23 alien alloys so far right now so my ship is ready, I'm going to clear the entire map to make sure I beat the game completely!